# I should not walk so fast

Tags: riddle

> I cannot wait for anyone,
>
> If I do, I can kill someone.
>
> I should not walk so fast,
>
> If I do, I will kill at last.
>
> You have me in you,
>
> Still I am coming for you.

What/Who am I?

Comment: Please provide a hint

Comment: @Kenshin It's been asked barely an hour ago.

Comment: last part sound like Mr. hide much?...

Answer (score 1):

Tend to agree with Techidiot that this appears very broad but

> it could be "HEART"

I cannot wait for anyone, 
If I do, I can kill someone.

> If your heart stops you die

I should not walk so fast, 
If I do, I will kill at last.

> Sounds like a heart attack

You have me in you, 
Still I am coming for you.

> There is literally a heart inside of each person, and it could be 'coming for you' figuratively?

If this is the answer, it'd be all too easy to make this less vague.

Comment: I also thought this may be the answer, however I was unsure of the part "Still I am coming for you"

Comment: +1 Though, again, in the current state of the riddle, it attracts a lot of answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Death?

I cannot wait for anyone

> Death doesn't wait if someone isn't prepared to die

If I do, I can kill someone.

> "Death is waiting for you" means you are going to die

I should not walk so fast,

> I'm not sure about this one

If I do, I will kill at last.

> but if Death walks fast, someone is probably going to die?

You have me in you,

> With life comes death

Still I am coming for you.

> eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt -

You are-

> **Blood Pressure**

I cannot wait for anyone,
If I do, I can kill someone.

> **Low blood pressure** can be fatal.

I should not walk so fast,
If I do, I will kill at last.

> **High blood pressure** can kill as well

You have me in you,
Still I am coming for you.

> We have a **normal blood pressure** within us.

Answer (score 0):

It is

> Time

I cannot wait for anyone,

> Time doesn't waits.

If I do, I can kill someone.

> If time stops, then every process stops and if it doesn't starts back it's equivalent to we are dead, everything is, that's why "can" not "will" (which we will see later)

I should not walk so fast,

> It's a general feeling that time passes so fast and we want the time to slow down, so Time feels I should not walk so fast even if it's the normal pace.

If I do, I will kill at last.

> "At last" here refers to the end of anything/everything/Universe. So Time is saying if it keeps walking there will be an end, for sure. See here it is "will" and before it was "I can kill", which makes the reasoning for "I can kill" more apt.

You have me in you,

> It's the 4th dimension so it's in everything, even in us.

Still I am coming for you.

> This is another way of saying "The clock is ticking". The Time cannot say that or like "I am ticking" so, " I am coming for you".

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Blood

I cannot wait for anyone, 
If I do, I can kill someone.

> Blood is involuntarily pumped through the body 24/7 as long you're alive. If blood stops running through the body, your brain will fail followed by your major internal organs etc.

I should not walk so fast, 
If I do, I will kill at last.

> Bleeding at a fast rate will lead to a slow death

You have me in you, 
Still I am coming for you.

> Blood is always in one's body but is always racing somewhere within us like our brain and heart

Answer (score 0):

It should be

> a shadow. It is coming from ourselves. And we are in our shadow. If I run fast then shadow run fast, if I run slow then shadow run slow. If I meet someone then  my shadow kills the other person's shadow.